# Extract Nested Array of Struct with If Else Logic

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue

I need to derive two new fields from the below schema structure - new columns `beaver_id` and `llama_id`. There is some if else logic that needs to be applied to an array of struct. The desired end result is a csv output. What is the best approach for this?

Schema:

```
root
 |-- Animal: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Species: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- unique_id: string (nullable = true)
```

Pseudo Code:

```
If name == "Beaver" 
   then get unique_id and put in dataframe column "beaver_id"
     else
   null in column "beaver_id"

If name == "Llama"
   then get unique_id and put in dataframe column "llama_id"
     else
   null in column "llama_id"

If array of names does not contain "Llama" or "Beaver"
   then null for both "beaver_id" and "llama_id"
```

Currently:
I am using select dataframe function to select elements out of the input (parquet) to create a csv output. I am extracting many other elements using this approach besides the ones in this question.

```
var select_df = raw_df.select(
  col(Animal.Species.name).getField("name")
  col(Animal.Species.color).getField("color")
)
```

Example Input (in JSON), Actual input is parquet:

```json
{
  "Animal": {
    "Species": [
      {
        "name": "Beaver",
        "color": "red",
        "unique_id": "1001"
      },
      {
        "name": "Llama",
        "color": "blue",
        "unique_id": "2222"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Expected csv output:

```
beaver_id, llama_id
1001, 2222
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#filter) function on `Animal.Species` array column like this:

```scala
val select_df = raw_df.select(
  element_at(expr("filter(Animal.Species, x -> x.name = 'Beaver')"), 1)
    .getField("unique_id")
    .as("beaver_id"),
  element_at(expr("filter(Animal.Species, x -> x.name = 'Llama')"), 1)
    .getField("unique_id")
    .as("llama_id")
)

select_df.show
//+---------+--------+
//|beaver_id|llama_id|
//+---------+--------+
//|     1001|    2222|
//+---------+--------+
```

The logic is quite simple, we filter the array to find the inner struct which holds `name = Beaver|Llama` and get its `unique_id`. If not found `null` is returned.

Note that since Spark 3, you can also use the [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#filter(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function within DataFrame API.

Comment: I think your solution is pretty clean. In Spark 3, using the filter function, would the syntax be the same except no expr function?

Comment: @Defcon yes it's the same syntax but in Scala API: `filter(col("Animal.Species"), x => x.getField("name") === lit("Beaver"))`

Comment: Is there a way to filter on an additional field using this same method? For example, if I wanted to know Beavers that are Blue.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to work with a large number of checks or with complex checks, it is always best to use a pattern strategy that simplifies this task, as well as adds scalability in case you want to add more checks.

In this sense, it seems more convenient to me that you create a context that determines what kind of "Species" is the record that you are verifying, in order to apply the logic you need, in this case, it would be the extraction of the required value and its subsequent assignment to the field determined by the context.

If I understood your question correctly, I think this would be the best approach for this task, let me know if my opinion fits your case and if you have any questions about it.